# Task Manager Glitch?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, virtualbox, task-manager

In task manager, under the "processes" tab, it shows that disk usage is 49% but in the "performance" tab, it shows that disk usage is 100%. I am using windows 8.1, core i5, 7200 RPM 1TB drive, 12 GB ram. At the time, I was setting up a virtual machine with virtual box. (The virtual hard drive was located on an external hard drive, the virtual box program was installed on local disk)

UPDATE: The task manager is viewing both the external hard drive and the internal drive, thus when the internal drive is at 100% while the external hard drive was at 0%, it will be shown as 50%.

Comment: Did you run the Task Manager "as administrator"? If not, then you're only going to see processes owned by you listed on the Processes tab. run is "as administrator" and check again.

Comment: Yeah, it still happens.